# Using fix to generate Fibonacci numbers recursively - how does this example work?

Tags: haskell

Good morning everyone!

Stackoverflow, being the rabbithole that it is, lead me to `fix` (the one that's contained in `Data.Fuction`), and since I'm already in the process of going through some of the more common Haskell libraries, and since `fix` seems to be a study subject all of it's own, I started reading up on it, first on Haskell Wiki (https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Fix_and_recursion) and then on this post ([https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/fix.xhtml](https://www.vex.net/%7Etrebla/haskell/fix.xhtml)), suggested by comments on a relevant thread.

In the latter, the writer presents four recursion examples and then goes through a couple of iterations to transform them in a form that's suitable for use with fix. I understand the thought process and I understand the final result. I also come to the conclusion, that the first two functions (`zeroes` and `fibs`) are examples of divergent computations, since they don't terminate, while the other two (`factorial` and `mapeven`) converge to a certain fixed point.

What really trips me up is the way the second function works, `fibs`.

It's pretty clear to me how `zeroes` works, since `fix f = let x = f x in x`. So, ghci,  knowing it has to compute `0:x`, will display `0` and then try to work out what `x` is, which turn out to be, again, `0:x`, so it will display that `0` and then again try to compute what `x` is, ad infinitum. In other words, it goes from 0:x to 0:(0:x) to 0:(0:(0:x)) etc, chasing it's own tail.

In the case of fibs, recursion seems to work kind of backwards. The function is `0:scanl (+) 1 x`, which is actually `0:scanl (+) 1 (0:scanl (+) 1 x)`. So what should ghci do? First of all, display `0`, since that's a given, and then work out what the result of `scanl` is. Well, for the first element that's easy, it should be the accumulator, or `1`, already provided for scanl. But then it should really work out what `x` actually is, in order to continue the computation, and `x` is `0:scanl (+) 1 x`, which is of course a list starting with 0, so the first scanl will add it's acc of `1` with `0` and give `1` as the third element of the computation, then add that `1` with the `acc` of the nested scanl function, again `1`, so, 2 becomes the fourth element of that chain of computations. But then the second scanl should really work out what `x` is, and that again turns out to be `0:scanl (+) 1 x`, so shouldn't the fifth element of that list be again `2`, which is the accumulator value of the second `scanl` function, plus `0`, as the first element of the newly evaluated `x`? How is it exactly that this computation goes on to output fibonacci numbers?. It seems to me like it should hang there forever (like, say `fix id`), because it should compute what `x` is in the first place.

If anyone can make heads or tails of this one (every pun intended), and explain it in a way that makes sense for the rest of us, I would very much aprreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to make sense of how Haskell programs are evaluated is rewriting. Haskell programs consist of *equations*, and those are used to unfold a main expression and enable further simplifications. The relevant equations here come from the definitions of `fix` and `scanl`.

```
x = 0 : scanl (+) 1 x

scanl (+) n (y : ys) = n : scanl (+) (n + y) ys
```

We want to evaluate x. Start by unfolding x

```
x = 0 : scanl (+) 1 x                           -- (1)
  = 0 : scanl (+) 1 (0 : scanl (+) 1 x)
```

This lets us use the `scanl` equation with `y = 0` and `ys = scanl (+) 1 x`.

```
x = 0 : 1 : scanl (+) (1 + 0) (scanl (+) 1 x)
  = 0 : 1 : scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x)         -- (2)
```

Next we need to unfold `scanl (+) 1 x`, and if we look above, we already did that work, deducing the following equation from those marked `(1)` and `(2)`

```
scanl (+) 1 x = 1 : scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x)
```

which lets us not repeat the work to unfold that latest occurrence of `scanl (+) 1 x`.

```
x = 0 : 1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x)))
```

Unfold `scanl`:

```
x = 0 : 1 : 1 : scanl (+) (1 + 1) (scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x))
  = 0 : 1 : 1 : scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x))         -- (3)
```

Again, we want to unfold `scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x)`, which we've already seen before (in `(2)`), and the result can be read in that last equation `(3)`.

```
x = 0 : 1 : 1 : scanl (+) 2 (1 : scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1 x)))
  = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : scanl (+) 3 (scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 (scanl (+) 1)))
```

And now we can see the accumulator `3` appear.

---

I tried to be smart and avoid doing work that was already done in some form. A more systematic method is to associate a variable to every new expression. In fact, this is quite close to how lazy evaluation is implemented in GHC: every variable is a memory location containing either an unevaluated expression, or a constructor applied to variables.

```
x = 0 : scanl (+) 1 x
```

Name the tail of the list.

```
x = 0 : x1
x1 = scanl (+) 1 x
```

Substitute and simplify

```
x1 = scanl (+) 1 (0 : x1)
   = 0 : scanl (+) 1 x1
```

Name the tail of the list

```
x1 = 0 : x2
x2 = scanl (+) 1 x1
```

etc.

```
x2 = scanl (+) 1 (0 : x2)
   = 1 : scanl (+) 1 x2
   = 1 : x3
x3 = scanl (+) 1 x2
   = scanl (+) 1 (1 : x3)
   = 1 : scanl (+) 2 x3
   = 1 : x4
x4 = 2 : x5
x5 = 3 : x6
x6 = 5 : x7
x7 = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Based on it, since the computation does not end, it seems like this approach progressively becomes a memory hog, correct? It looks like that, since nested expansions of x keep piling up...

Comment: Not necessarily. The list is infinite, but (1) it is computed on-demand and (2) later variables don't refer to earlier ones, so if the list is consumed in a streaming fashion (without keeping hold of its root), garbage collection will make it so only the relevant bits are kept in memory.